# MKAnnotationView not displayed when object creation is performed within a custom annotation class

Tags: ios, mkannotationview

**Environment**

Xcode: 5.0.2, Device: iPhone,
iOS: iOS 7

I am trying to use the `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` delegate method.  Within this method, if I create the `MKAnnotationView` object, the pin gets displayed without any issue. Here is the working code:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomeAnnotation class]])
    {
        //  CustomeAnnotation *myLocation = (CustomeAnnotation *)annotation;
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomAnnotation"];

        if (annotationView == nil)
        {
            MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MyCustomAnnotation"];
            annotationView.enabled = YES;
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
            //annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"park_icon"];
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        }
        //   annotationView = myLocation.createAnnotationView;
        else
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;

          //return nil;
        return annotationView;

    }
    else
        return nil;
}
```

When I create a class method and move the `MKAnnotationView` object creation and property setting within the class method and I call it from the `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` delegate method, the pin does not appear.

Here is the code for the two methods in question (`mapView:viewForAnnotation:` and `createAnnotationView`):

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D baysideParkCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(25.774407, -80.185797);
    CustomeAnnotation *baysideParkAnnotation = [[CustomeAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@" Bayfront Park"
                                                                             coordinate:baysideParkCoordinates];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:baysideParkAnnotation];

}

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomeAnnotation class]])
    {
        CustomeAnnotation *myLocation = (CustomeAnnotation *)annotation;
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomAnnotation"];

        if (annotationView == nil)
                annotationView = [myLocation createAnnotationView];
        else
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;

      //  return nil;
        return annotationView;

    }
    else
        return nil;
}

@end
```

The custom class

```
#import "CustomeAnnotation.h"

@implementation CustomeAnnotation

-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)newTitle coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) newCoordinate
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.title = newTitle;
        self.coordinate = newCoordinate;
    }
    return self;
}


-(MKAnnotationView *)createAnnotationView
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:self reuseIdentifier:@"MyCustomAnnotation"];
    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    //annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"park_icon"];
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    return annotationView;
}
@end
```

The import statement for the CustomeAnnotation class is included in the ViewController.h file.

At this point I believe I am not passing back correctly the `MKAnnotationView` object back to the method call in the ViewController implementation file.  Could anyone tell me what is it that I am doing wrong on the second set of code?

Answer (score 0):

In the **second** set of code, in `createAnnotationView`, the annotation is not showing because it's not setting the `image`.

Note that an `MKAnnotationView` does not have a default image so if you don't set it, the annotation is invisible.

Uncomment the setting of the `image` (or create an `MKPinAnnotationView` instead).

The reason the **first** set of code works (even though it is also creating an `MKAnnotationView`) is because there's actually a small bug in the code:

```
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeue...

if (annotationView == nil)
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] init...
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Here, the code declares a NEW, LOCAL variable
    //                 named annotationView but it has no connection to the
    //                 annotationView declared outside the if-block.
```

Because the `annotationView` declared outside the `if` is never set, it stays `nil` and that's what the delegate method actually returns.

When you return `nil` from `viewForAnnotation`, the map view creates a default view for you (a red pin for your annotations, a blue dot for the user location).

To fix the first set of code, don't declare a new, local variable.  Just set the variable:

```
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeue...

if (annotationView == nil)
{
    annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] init...
```

and don't forget to set the `image` (or create an `MKPinAnnotationView` instead).